# Jmeter Nested Http Request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have been trying to do a nested API call
Where in my calls as to go like this-

1. first call - 1 time
2. second call - n number of times (usually 800)
3. third call- 1 time

The API would be the same and the request body differs-

**first call -**

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "last" : false ,
    "value" : "" ,
    "order" : 0
}
```

**second call -**

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "last" : false ,
    "value" : "A" ,
    "order" : 1 to n 
}
```

**third call -**

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "last" : true ,
    "value" : "" ,
    "order" : 1
}
```

My CSV looks like this -

**file-1**

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

**file-2**

| order | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

File-1: I pick **id** from file 1 which is used in all three calls.

File-2: I pick **order** and **value** which is to be looped n number of times.

I want the execution to happen like this -

```
 for() {
       // first call
        for() {
           // second call
        }
      // third call
    }
```

When I do this with my JMeter configuration -

Thread ends at second call ( end of CSV file content ), I'm not able to make 3rd API call.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your CSV Data Set Config has both `Recycle on EOF` and `Stop thred on EOF` set to `False`

   [image]
2. Instead of using Loop Controller switch to [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
    ${__jexl3("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: no, this dint work, I have two CSV files to loop.